# Saving dropdown values inside gridview to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, save

I'm working on a web application. I have gridview on my main page that contains labels and three dropdown list. I also have a save button outside my gridview. The button should save the values should there be changes made in the drop down per row. My problem now is how to achieve the saving. For example, I have 5 rows, I only updated two rows and when I hit save button the two rows should only be saved. the others will remain unchanged. Please help. See my code below. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Are you showing the previous values in the `DropDownList` from database?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the gridview and pickup the selected values inside the dropdown and save it...

```
for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DropDownList ddl1= (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].FindControl("Dropdownlist1");
   string abc=ddl.selectedvalue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, this code applies to all the rows regardless if I updated or not, correct? I'd like to save all the updated records only. I updated my code with my current implementation, but it seems I'm missing something. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

- Provide edit/delete button on each row in readonly mode.
- When clicked on edit button make the row in editable mode and change the edit button to update button.
- After making changes click update button, save the new values to the database and make the gridview back to the readonly mode showing edit/delete buttons.

[Helpful Link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, however the design should be same on my code. Only one button outside the gridview should be used (which is the save button)

Comment: You can try using a global datatable whose datacolumns match same as your gridview column plus one more additional boolean column ("IsEdited").

Set the IsEdited flag and Dropdown's changed value in datatable rows when event 'onselectedindexchanged'  triggered in dropdown.